# How to display first image from a list of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, postman

I am passing a prop called product which has a list of objects inside a variable images. I want to display first image with id number 1 on the frontend.  Also if I want to iterate through the images what would be the best way. I have attached the object image as seen on postman as a photo.  I am trying to display this line in the card <Card.Img src={product.images} />

```
{
    function Product({ product }) {
    return (
        
        <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
            <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
                <Card.Img src={product.images} />
            </Link>

            <Card.Body>
                <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
                    <Card.Title as="div">
                        <strong>{product.name}</strong>
                    </Card.Title>
                </Link>

                <Card.Text as="div">
                    <div className="my-3">
                        <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`} color={'#f8e825'} />
                    </div>
                </Card.Text>


                <Card.Text as="h3">
                    ${product.price}
                </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: To display first image try, `product.images[0].image` . To iterate all images use like `product.images.map(item => <Card.Img src={item.image} />);`

Comment: BTW, I am not the down voter here. But always follow the standard of asking the question. You can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I had already tried your solution, but it was not working due to some other issues in the product being uploaded itself.  Once the answer was confirmed by you, I updated all the other products. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

try this,
{product.images[0].image}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
<Card.Img src={product.images[0].image} />
```

would be the solution to show the first image.

and for the second, if i understood right, you should try to put a loop surrounding,

```
<Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
    <Card.Img src={product.images} />
</Link>
```

this, and render the data accordingly